# Rider: Debug remote applications running in a docker container on WSL2 via SSH

Tags: c#, .net, docker, wsl-2, rider

There is [Rider's documentation on how to debug remote applications via SSH](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/SSH_Remote_Debugging.html), and it perfectly works when I debug applications running on WSL2. But it doesn't work on debugging an application running in a docker container inside WSL2. Rider even shows this application in the "Run" -> "Attach to Remote Process" menu but can't attach to it (no errors but doesn't attach).

I probably need to run JetBrains SSH Server Utility inside a docker container where the application is running and share the ports, but I don't know how to do it properly.

**Edit:** For clarity, I added a diagram of what I want to get as a result.

[image]

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you already ask the [Rider support](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=97145)? Usually they are very helpful

Comment: @mu88 thanks for the advice, I asked it here: https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/3814175

Comment: Crossing fingers that they can help you! If you find a solution, I'd really appreciate if you share it here :)

Comment: @hcp did you find an answer to this? I'm looking for the exact same thing

Comment: Please, post a docker command you are using to start container

Answer (score 1):

Below is a solution to debug Rider remotely inside a Docker container. The exact solution will depend on your specific environment and what kind of image you are building with Docker. The steps are generally going to be as follows:

1. Download the appropriate JetBrains SSH agent inside your `Dockerfile`
2. Setup necessary permissions to run it (some images may not run as `root`)
3. Create a wrapper `entrypoint` script that first executes the SSH agent, and then executes your app.
4. Set this `entrypoint` as the default `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` in your `Dockerfile`
5. Run the image, forwarding the necessary debugger port

From there, the steps are the same as any other remote SSH connection.

Assume you have a `Dockerfile` building your app on `ubuntu`:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
WORKDIR /usr/local/app

# Copy required files including entrypoint wrapper
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN \
   # replace with the appropriate arch as needed
   curl -L "https://download.jetbrains.com/rider/ssh-remote-debugging/linux-x64/jetbrains_debugger_agent_20230319.24.0" \
    -o /usr/local/bin/debugger && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/debugger

# debugging port
EXPOSE 7777

# expose your actual application ports e.g.
# EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/local/bin/debugger -port 7777 &
# execute your actual application next
# e.g. `node index.js`
sleep 1d
```

Next, build the image including your application with debugging symbols enabled:

```bash
$ docker build -t jetdebug .
[+] Building 13.2s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 532B                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 170B                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /usr/local/app                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [3/5] COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [4/5] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl                                                                                                                                                                            10.7s
 => [5/5] RUN    curl -L "https://download.jetbrains.com/rider/ssh-remote-debugging/linux-x64/jetbrains_debugger_agent_20230319.24.0"     -o /usr/local/bin/debugger &&     chmod +x /usr/local/bin/debugger                        2.3s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.2s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.2s 
 => => writing image sha256:b98a6356808dd97fe1222892914305fcf1f47e709ac68bde41077a8a24769563                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/jetdebug
```

Finally, start the container:

```
$ docker run --rm -i -p7777:7777 jetdebug                                                                                                                                                                        
Using host key fingerprint SHA256:ietD1qIhLzcDNcmH/dm2kp6us1j8QRa4yErNhn7vAYo
Please use these credentials to establish SSH connection:

Login:  root
Password:  ajpOUbr7dNLIp1gy
Port:  7777

Copy the three lines above and switch to Rider: it will detect the credentials in the clipboard and suggest adding a new remote host configuration with these login, password, and port.
Note: you will still need to specify the host name manually.
```

> Note that `-p7777:7777` flag specifies forwarding port `7777` when running the container. If you are doing this on a separate server, you may need to change firewall settings to further allow access to the port remotely.

We can see now on the host that port `7777` is forwarded correctly to the debugging SSH agent:

```bash
$ nc -v localhost 7777
Connection to localhost (127.0.0.1) 7777 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
SSH-2.0-Go
^C
```

From here, you can connect remotely as per normal in Rider.

If your application uses a different base Docker image, the steps are the same, but may need to be adjusted for the OS and architecture involved.

The `entrypoint` logic can obviously be written in any language.

Also note that this setup contains several anti-patterns and would never be recommended for any kind of production deployment. Besides the fact that debugging symbols should never be in production code, containers should only contain [one concern](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#decouple-applications) and the debugging SSH process is not monitored by the `docker` process in the case it should unexpectedly crash.