# Include Rider Debug Tools in a Dockerfile

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, rider

I'm trying to setup a development environment for some dotnet projects in Rider using docker compose and I can't find an elegant way of debugging them.

I'm using docker compose's "watch" functionality to automatically rebuild the containers when I make some code changes, although this then means I need to re-attach to the container in Rider and reinstall the debug tools to the container each time it is rebuilt.

[image]

Is there a way to add these tools to the dockerfile so they don't have to be manually installed each time? Alternatively is there an easier way to develop and debug dotnet projects when running inside docker?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70964260/rider-debug-remote-applications-running-in-a-docker-container-on-wsl2-via-ssh#:%7E:text=FROM%20ubuntu%3A,entrypoint.sh%22%5D) as a previous suggestion, but Rider still prompted me to install the debugging tools.